# Cannot change PhoneBackgroundColor in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

My app is prefer to uses light theme of Windows Phone 7 although the the phone theme is dark.
I have use the code below but it doesn't work.

```
        var background = (Color)Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"];
        background.R = 240;
        background.G = 240;
        background.B = 240;
        var brushBackground = Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
        brushBackground.Color = background;
```

Please help me.

Comment: You have defined two variables `background` and `brushBackground`, fine.
Then what do you want to do with them? or what are you doing with them? If you don't want your app depend on the phone theme..then set your own backgrounds, instead of depending on `PhoneBackground` properties

Answer (score 0):

Use Jeff Wilcox's Theme Manager.
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/

It's easy to use, add a file and a single line of code:

```
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```

And you have a App that always uses the Light Theme.